# Invalid type for argument in function call

Tags: tokens

I have this token code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract MyToken {

   mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

   function MyToken(uint256 _supply) public {

     balanceOf[msg.sender] = _supply;  
 }
    //ф-ция должна так называться по ERC20
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public
      {
    //проверка, хватает ли токенов у того, кто хочет отправить  
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender]) >= _value;

    //проверка, не произошло ли переполнение
   require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);

   //забираем токены у отправителя
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;

   //передаем токены получателю
      balanceOf[_to] += _value; 
   }
}
```

And there is an error  in the line 
 = _value;>

Answer (score 1):

The right line is:

```
require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
```

Comment: Try to elaborate more to make it more helful

Answer (score 0):

don't worry it's just a type error, you need to put `>= _value` inside require statement.

Replace this:

```
require(balanceOf[msg.sender]) >= _value;
```

With:

```
require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
```